# Subdomain in Node with Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, subdomain

I have a Node app hosted on Heroku. I want to create a subdomain for part of this app (when users are logged in) something like console.myappname.heroku.com I tried the [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain) module but it doesn't seem to work.